# Reading and iterating though a JSON object angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing an angular website and I am new to the platform. I am trying to get data from a web service in JSON format then just output it. I have seen many examples where the data is first piped into an array of a class/model. But I would like to know if there is an easier way where I do not have to do this extra data structure. (This is a really simple application)

In my typescript class:

```
export class TestimonialsComponent implements OnInit {

  public testimonials: Observable<any[]>;
  baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:80/';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  get_testimonials(){
      this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl).subscribe((res : any[])=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.testimonials = res;
      });
  }
```

And in the HTML file

```
<button (click)="get_testimonials()">GET /products</button>



<li *ngFor='let testimonial of testimonials | async'>
  {{ testimonial.Name }}
</li>
```

The console successfully sees my object but I get this error message when I try to do the iteration:

ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could use your code without the async pipe.

```
<li *ngFor='let testimonial of testimonials'>
  {{ testimonial.Name }}
</li>
```

There are benefits and drawback in both approaches. I found that without sync I have more control on error handling and loading indicators. But I suspect it can be solved with async to. 
Tip: get_testimonials should be written getTestimonials

Comment: I get exactly the same error if I try this approach

Comment: NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. Check the data you get from the observable.  console.log(res); Is it an array? Is it not set? You can also what data is transfered in f12 console. Is the array located in a property?

Comment: public testimonials: Observable<any[]>; should be  public testimonials: any[]; as Ajit Nikam wrote

Comment: sofar it's not working yet, I have an idea the issue is somewhere to do with array vs object. It says array but the curly brackets indicate object as far as I understand, neither approaches worked. Here is the log in the console for my original code:
  ~~~
    {data: Array(4)}
    data: Array(4)
    0: {ID: "1", Name: "Ian", Body: "THis is awesome"}
    1: {ID: "2", Name: "Ian", Body: "THis is awesome"}
    2: {ID: "3", Name: "Morne", Body: "THis is awesome2"}
    3: {ID: "4", Name: "KB", Body: "THis is awesome3"}
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array(0)
    __proto__: Object
  ~~~

Comment: I think the array is located in the property  data. try: testimonials.data

Comment: or better change this.testimonials = res.data (and then keep:  let testimonial of testimonials)

Answer (score 1):

**The Error you are getting because of Async pipe**

To know more about Async Pipe visit below link
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Make Below changes in your code:

In typescript file:

```
 public testimonials: any[];
```

In Html file:

```
<li *ngFor='let testimonial of testimonials'>
    {{ testimonial.Name}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

enclose the `testimonials | async` into a parentheses which is much cleaner code

```
let testimonial of (testimonials | async)
```

and in the service do not subscribe to the http observable. the testimonials property should be an Observable.

```
get_testimonials(){this.testimonials = this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl)};
```

the `async` will automatically subscribe and get the testimonials.

Comment: If I try this I now get this error:

ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.